# how to use windowScriptObject on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Greetings!

I was wondering how I could use javascript code on an iPhone application I was developing. this [tutorial](http://will.thimbleby.net/script/) illustrated how to use windowScriptObjects for Cocoa application. However, I have been unable to locate something similar for UIWebViews.

does this functionality actually exist in Cocoa touch? and if yes, could anyone point me to the right direction as to how I might start using it.

thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Like rpetrich said, this is Non-Public API so the windowScriptObject route might not be the best.

I did find this link though, which helped me a lot:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/7731057?messageID=7731057�

Basically, if you can keep your interactions between HTML and Objective-C entirely based on the user clicking links ( a href="" )
then all of this can be easily communicated between the two.

While it would be nice, I agree, to exchange variables and call methods at will, this already gives you a lot to work with. Hope that's useful!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not exposed via a public API.