# windowScriptObject method not found on Objective-C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebView` with my application and want to call `Objective-C` method from JavaScript.
All documentation and tutorial that I found, I see is just uses the `windowScriptObject` method, but in my code `Xcode` says that webView dont have instance method `-windowScriptObject`.

What's wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    id win = [webView windowScriptObject]; // In this line, Xcode alert 'Instance method "-windowScriptObject" not found'
    [win setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"isExtended"];
}
```

Comment: `windowScriptObject` seems not to be available on iOS. Check similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501618/how-to-use-windowscriptobject-on-the-iphone

Comment: @MichałZygar — post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`windowScriptObject` seems not to be available on iOS. [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also, check similar question: [how to use windowScriptObject on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501618/how-to-use-windowscriptobject-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Thanks... I'll try other strategy

Comment: This is not exactly what he asked...The question is how to invoke a objective c method from javascript and the objective c method should return some values to javascript