# Run JavaScript from Objective-C error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm pretty new in this so don't be harsh on me.

I have a web page that when a button is clicked, it does a change of URL, this is detected by Objective-C and opens the Camera.

Until here fine.

Now I want to return the image to the webview but I cant.
I'm trying to run a JavaScript to do it as it says the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html)

When the image is taken and used, this method runs:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
//self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
id win = [_webView windowScriptObject];
[win evaluateWebScript: @"addImage(’sample_graphic.jpg’, ‘320’, ‘240’)"]; //HERE instead of the string, I want to send 'chosenImage' 
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

But I get the errors:

```
 No visible @interface for UIWebView declares selector 'windowScriptObject'
```

Which I don't really know what it means.
Have to say that this is coded in the WebViewController, which is my only and root controller.

Comment: What's _webView? An UIWebView? If yes, it doesn't have this kind of property or method (windowScriptObject).

Comment: in the .m is: `@synthesize webView = _webView;`
And in .h is:`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;`

Comment: From where did you get `windowScriptObject`?

Comment: thats what they do here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html

Comment: From MAC OS X, and not from iOS. That's the issue, this doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: Do you actually want to execute a javascript method in iOS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701835/windowscriptobject-method-not-found-on-objective-c-code

Comment: I want to run a JS that is in the web page, because I think there is no way to capture an ajax call and return a value

Comment: why you don't use cordova ?

Comment: cant use anything like that, cant rely on other persons copyrights

Comment: Did you try: [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"YOUR JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION()"];

Comment: but can I add there all the parameters like I was pretending to do before??