# How to Edit in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

hello I have html then I have loaded this html on UIWebView  now i want to editing in this html and save this and also want to convert this Editable  WebView data into Html For this I am using CK Editor this work perfectly but this is not smooth so iOS have any documentation which do this Without using .js and .css file like as iWork this is as a simple Editor but i don't know how I use it Please tell me

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share code and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Please; even if you are not fluent in English, you can use capitals and punctuation to create a much more readable text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the scripting object of UIWebView, and then do some work on the javascript side to send the data out of the web view, into your view controller. Then you can do whatever you want with it. Save as a document etc.

Please take a look at this: windowScriptObject

Unfortunately I think this is still a private API in iOS (unlike on the Mac). But looking at solutions around this topic, you may find something.

And please use interpunction.

Comment: You are correct `widnowScriptObject` is not a public API so can't be used please see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501618/how-to-use-windowscriptobject-on-the-iphone +1 for noting this